# Keep whitespaces in RTE for pre and code tags

Tags: typo3, rte

I want to display code through `<pre>` and/or `<code>` tags, which works fine. White spaces are saved on first save and displayed properly in the front-end. However, when reloading the content in the backend, the editor shows the code without the additional whitespaces. Saving again drops the whole code formatting.

I assume there is some setting for this but I couldn't find anything until now. Any hints on this?

For the code highlighting, I am using the `GeshiLib` and `vjrtecodesnippets`extensions.

**Edit:**

Sorry, missed the configuration. There is the basic `rtehtmlarea` involved, currently v4.7.5, there is no TCA specific change since it is a standard bodytext field from TYPO3's standard *Text content element* (displayed through `css_styled_content`).

PageTS for the RTE looks like the following:

```
RTE.default.hidePStyleItems := removeFromList(pre)
RTE.default.proc {
  allowTags := addToList(pre)
  entryHTMLparser_db.allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags

  overruleMode = tx_vjrtecodesnippets,ts_css,cleanenc
  allowTags := addToList(code)
  allowTagsOutside := addToList(code)

  entryHTMLparser_db {
    allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
    allowTagsOutside < RTE.default.proc.allowTagsOutside
  }

  HTMLparser_rte {
    allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
    allowTagsOutside < RTE.default.proc.allowTagsOutside
  }
}
```

**Edit2:** We've published the TYPO3 extension news_blog which does exactly this.

Comment: Could you post the TCA configuration for the field and the table, please? Is there an RTE involved somewhere?

Comment: Ok, so what you are seeing here is the RTE's parser at work. It tries to optimize the HTML. Do you need the RTE in the backend? Could you perhaps just use a plain old textfield?

Otherwise, you'ld have to configure the parsefunc, and that's a real hassle.

Comment: I need the RTE in the backend since the syntax highlighter should also work for the bodytext field in news and other extensions. Could you give me a starting hint so I could try and hassle a bit?

Comment: Hm... you might need to turn of the parsing or write your own parsefunc, then.

Google for parseFunc in conjunction with RTE

Comment: Just realized: This link may help: http://www.van-tomas.de/blog/how-to-enable-custom-tags-in-typo3-rte/

Comment: Which version of TYPO3, rtehtmlarea?

Comment: 4.7.5, as written in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to write a comment, but a short answer with sophisticated guesses might be just as good:

- I checked at my own site, the `<code>` tag works fine. Whitespaces
  are stored as `&nbsp;` in the bodytext field, therefore preserved
  when saved and re-opened.
- Have you tried deleting the line
  `RTE.default.hidePStyleItems := removeFromList(pre)`?
- According to the [manual](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/vjrtecodesnippets/0.0.4/view/1/2/), only `<code>` tags are supported by `vjrtecodesnippets`. Do you really need *both* tags for syntax highlighting?
- Also, have you tried changing your PageTS like follows to enable `<pre>`?:

-

```
RTE.default.proc {
  allowTagsOutside := addToList(code,pre)
}
```

**EDIT:**
I found a related [TypoScript snippet](http://snipplr.com/view/9197/), which might be noteworthy for your case. Please try making the following adjustments:

In the Template SETUP section:

```
lib.parseFunc.allowTags := addToList(code,pre)
lib.parseFunc_RTE.allowTags := addToList(code,pre)
```

In the PAGE TSconfig:

```
RTE.default.proc {
  allowTags := addToList(code,pre)
  allowTagsOutside := addToList(code,pre)
  overruleMode = tx_vjrtecodesnippets,ts_css,cleanenc

  // CONTENT TO DATABASE
  HTMLparser_rte {
    allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
    allowTagsOutside < RTE.default.proc.allowTagsOutside
  }

  // Entry HTML parser
  entryHTMLparser_db {
    allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
    allowTagsOutside < RTE.default.proc.allowTagsOutside
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this works on typo3 7.4

```
    RTE.default.proc {
    allowTags := addToList(pre)

    HTMLparser_rte {
        allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
    }

    entryHTMLparser_db {
        allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
    }
}
```

for sure you can also add more tag names seperated with " , "

for more settings to your RTE in typoscript check out. 
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/6.2/Rte/Transformations/Tsconfig/Index.html