# TYPO3 tinymce_rte pre and code

Tags: tinymce, typo3

I try to get `pre`- and `code`-tags get running with tinymce_rte. But the RTE removes all spaces and tabs. Have someone experience in this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I understand, use of other editors than the onboard RTE is discouraged in TYPO3. Which is a bit of a pity (I myself would like to use markitup), but on the other hand, there are more resources for the RTE. E.g. see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172051/keep-whitespaces-in-rte-for-pre-and-code-tags

Comment: really all spaces and tabs, or just the spaces and tabs at the start of the editor content?

Comment: @Urs: I have seen this question, but it's for rtehtmlarea. And I found now where this will be parsed (RteHtmlParser.php). There is no option to set to prevent this. I'll use now an highlighter extension. I spent already the last day with this issue :(